# What is the special meaning of parenthesis around anonymous functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators, anonymous-function, javascript-objects, parentheses

In my javascript console surrounding a value with parenthesis doesn't change the output.

```
1
=> 1
(1)
=> 1
```

Same thing with a string variable:

```
x = "foo"
=> "foo"
x
=> "foo"
(x)
=> "foo"
```

Same thing with a function in a variable:

```
f = function(){}
=> function (){}
f
=> function (){}
(f)
=> function (){}
```

If I don't assign the function to a variable I get an error:

```
function(){}
=> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ((…)
```

Surrounding the anonymous function with parenthesis and I get the expected result:

```
(function(){})
=> function (){}
```

Why is this?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Putting the function definition inside the grouping operator forces the definition to be evaluated as *function expression* (because the grouping operator can only contain an expression) as opposed to a *function declaration* (without the parens). The name is optional in function expressions but not in function declarations. It's the same as `{"foo": 42}` vs `({"foo": 42})`, i.e. forcing the parser to interpret this as an *object initializer*, not a *block*.

Comment: Along with what Felix Kling mentioned, this means that wrapping the function inside `(...)` allows you to call it directly. For example: `(function(){alert("test")})()` will do `alert("test")`.

Comment: See http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html.